# Haskell trouble writing bind function for a monad instance (function transformation?)

Tags: haskell, bind, monads

I need to write the following function:

```
bind :: ((a -> Action) -> Action) -> (a -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)) -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)
```

Action is a type constructor that I defined. Trouble is when I try to implement it in the following way:

```
bind f g =
```

I do not know how to pass a value of type "a" to the function g. I am clueless regarding to get the value.

As a matter of fact this looks like some kind of transforming one function to another, but I also don't know how to achieve that.

What should I do to make this transformation possible?

Comment: Look at the `chainCPS` function [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style).

Comment: Use Djinn. It implement that for you.

Comment: This is an exercise on Erik Meijer's fp101x. You'll not learn if you outsource your homework. There are quite a lot of guidance in the course material: "Now you can let the types lead you to the only reasonable implementation." - even Djinn in fact will find the right instance for you, it's educational to do that exercise on your own, maybe even with pen & paper. The solution is short. Don't spoil yourself the "Eureka" moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the Cont monad bind. Without a newtype wrapper it looks like this:

```
bind :: ((a -> r) -> r) -> (a -> ((b -> r) -> r)) -> ((b -> r) -> r)
```

First, remove redundant brackets:

```
bind :: ((a -> r) -> r) -> (a -> (b -> r) -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r
```

Second, let `b -> r = br`:

```
bind :: ((a -> r) -> r) -> (a -> br -> r) -> br -> r
```

Now you have

```
bind s f k = ?
```

where `s :: (a -> r) -> r`, `f :: a -> br -> r` and `k :: br`.

And

```
flip f k     :: a -> r
s (flip f k) :: r
```

so

```
bind :: ((a -> r) -> r) -> (a -> ((b -> r) -> r)) -> ((b -> r) -> r)
bind s f k = s (flip f k)
```

Or simply

```
bind s f = s . flip f
```

Or in pointfree

```
bind = (. flip) . (.)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your monad is called the continuation monad `Cont r a = ((a->r)->r)` (minus a newtype wrapper) where `r = Action` in your case. But let's adventure a bit without looking at how that monad is defined...

Let's boldly start with:

```
bind :: forall a b. ((a -> Action) -> Action) -> (a -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)) -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)
bind f g = (??? :: (b -> Action) -> Action)
```

So, let's start filling the `???`. We need to produce a function, so let's exploit a lambda for that:

```
bind :: forall a b. ((a -> Action) -> Action) -> (a -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)) -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)
bind f g = \k :: (b -> Action) -> (??? :: Action)
```

Once having overcome that, we now need to craft an `Action`. We have several functions in our hands returning that: `f,g,k`, each requiring different args. This is a matter of trial-and-error. Let's guess... `f`.

```
bind :: forall a b. ((a -> Action) -> Action) -> (a -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)) -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)
bind f g = \k :: (b -> Action) -> f (??? :: a -> Action)
```

We again need a function: sprinkle more lambdas, more lambdas!

```
bind :: forall a b. ((a -> Action) -> Action) -> (a -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)) -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)
bind f g = \k :: (b -> Action) -> f (\x :: a -> (??? :: Action))
```

Groan..., we need again to produce an `Action`. Was what we did pointless? Are we looping in circles? *No*, we now have `x :: a` in scope, so we now grew in power. Let's use `g` now:

```
bind :: forall a b. ((a -> Action) -> Action) -> (a -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)) -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)
bind f g = \k :: (b -> Action) -> f (\x :: a -> g (???1 : a) (???2 :: b -> Action))
```

Well, the first argument of `g` is now trivial to find.

```
bind :: forall a b. ((a -> Action) -> Action) -> (a -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)) -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)
bind f g = \k :: (b -> Action) -> f (\x :: a -> g x (???2 :: b -> Action))
```

More lambdas, more lambdas!

```
bind :: forall a b. ((a -> Action) -> Action) -> (a -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)) -> ((b -> Action) -> Action)
bind f g = \k :: (b -> Action) -> f (\x :: a -> g x (\y :: b -> (??? :: Action)))
```

Argh! Not another `Action` to produce! But all is not lost, we grew in power: we now have both `x::a` and `y::b` at our call! We also never used `k`... uhm....

To do:

1. Defeat the last `???`.
2. Provide a `return`/unit function for the monad.
3. Prove the monad laws.
4. Profit!